# Android Studio 'Obsolete Gradle Dependency' inspection issue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have following gradle dependencies in my Android build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```

Declared versions are the current latest stable versions of these libraries([android support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)). But Android Studio displays following warning on them.

> A newer version of  exists than 23.2.1 is available:
>   24.0.0-alpha1
>   [image]

24.0.0-alpha1 seems to be the newly released developer preview and I don't want to take them as a stable version of libraries. I can suppress or disable this inspection and get rid of the warnings. But doing so will avoid valid future warnings as well.

How can git rid of this warning for the developer previews?. The warning should appear only if valid new stable version of the library exists.

I use Android studio 1.5.1
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys from Google has already fixed it, so all that you need to do now is to wait for the next update.
This problem has already been reported here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203321